# What exactly happens when ubuntu recovers from crash?

Tags: 10.04, configuration

I've experiences some configuration "resets" after ubuntu crashes:

- Display configuration changed (I'd changing through `/usr/bin/nvidia-settings`)
- Hibernation/Suspension turned on again (I'd disabled it)

In order to prevent those, I would like to know **how exactly ubuntu recovers from crashes**.

***Background**: I'm particulary intereseted in this topic because I've ubuntu connected to displays showing information across a public building. And it's pretty embarassing when the display config is all messed up and sometimes going all black (resolution not supported).*

Comment: You might wanna track down the problem which crashes the system instead of finding away around recovering methods. If the system is constantly crashing every few hours, I'd suspect a hardware problem or a problem with the used software. Does `dmesg` output anything of interest, or maybe `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: Sadly, some crashes are inevitable. e.g.: the cleaning personal ungplugs the machine to plug the vacuum cleaner; blackouts; ... I want to be covered even in those cases.

Comment: Ubuntu should recover from those 'sudden' shutoffs without any complications, at least Lucid did. So if your X-Settings are getting reset, it's most likely a problem with the driver or with the XServer itself, only in that case Bulletproof-X should jump in and revert the settings.

Comment: hatou saved your settings to the xorg.conf file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ubuntu does nothing beyond normal filesystem checks when recovering from a crash. If you're seeing changes to configurations, perhaps the filesystem is not handling crashes very well (on a crash, it will just run a standard `fsck`). Try identifying which files are changing that are causing you the problem. (What commands do you run to save the settings, etc?)

If this is a public display system, you may want to investigate replacement hardware (crashing every few hours sounds like a more serious problem), or checking to see if whatever you're displaying is not leaking memory and triggering the [Out-Of-Memory killer](http://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer). (Keep an eye on the output of `free` between reboot and the crash.)

Comment: Thanks @Kees-Cook. The system is not crashing every few hours, I didn't mean that. My bad, I've just edited that